# Android how to change listview array with intent?

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, android-intent

these are my activity, I wanted to know if you could set that depending on the button you could change the array in the next activty Is it possible?

(ACTIVITY A)

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gruppipuntate_activity);

    //rimozione action bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
    }
    //gestione Switch java per selezione puntate
    final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
             switch(v.getId()){ 
             case R.id.button1:
                break;
             case R.id.button2:
                break;
             case R.id.button3:
                break;
             case R.id.button4:
                break;
             case R.id.button5:
                break;
             case R.id.button6:
                break;
             case R.id.button7:
                break;
             case R.id.button8:
                break;
             case R.id.button9:
                break;
             case R.id.button10:
                break;
             }
         }
    };
    final int[] btnIds = new int[]{R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4
            , R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10};
    for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) {
        final Button puntate = (Button)findViewById(btnIds[i]);
        puntate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //preparazione intent
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //azioni da fare
                //definisco l'intenzione da fare con il pulsante
                Intent episodi = new Intent(GruppiPuntateActivity.this,EpisodiActivity.class);
                //faccio aprire l'activity desiderata
                startActivity(episodi);
        }
    });

    }
}
}
```

(ACTIVITY B)

```
findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        findViewById(R.id.textList1);

    // definisco un array di stringhe  
    String[] Product = new String[] { "Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4", "Product5", "Product6", "Product7", "Product8", "Product9" };   

    // definisco un ArrayList  
    final ArrayList <String> listp = new ArrayList<String>();  
    for (int i = 0; i < Product.length; ++i) {  
         listp.add(Product[i]);  
    }  
    // recupero la lista dal layout  
    final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  

    // creo e istruisco l'adattatore  
    final ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listp);  

    // inietto i dati  
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: best way is to use serializable extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

ACTIVITY A:

```
ArrayList<String> products;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gruppipuntate_activity);

    //rimozione action bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
    }
    //gestione Switch java per selezione puntate
    final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
                int index = -1;
                switch(v.getId()){ 
                case R.id.button1:
                index = products.indexOf("Product1");
                    if(index >= 0)
                        products.remove(index);
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    index = products.indexOf("Product2");
                    if(index >= 0)
                        products.remove(index);
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    break;
                case R.id.button5:
                    break;
                case R.id.button6:
                    break;
                case R.id.button7:
                    break;
                case R.id.button8:
                    break;
                case R.id.button9:
                    break;
                case R.id.button10:
                    break;
             }
         }
    };
    final int[] btnIds = new int[]{R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4
            , R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10};
    for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) {
        final Button puntate = (Button)findViewById(btnIds[i]);
        puntate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //preparazione intent
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent episodi = new Intent(GruppiPuntateActivity.this,EpisodiActivity.class);
                episodi.putStringArrayListExtra("products", products);
                startActivity(episodi);
        }
    });

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    products = new ArrayList<String>();
    products.add("Product1");
    products.add("Product2");
    products.add("Product3");
    products.add("Product4");
    products.add("Product5");
    products.add("Product6"); 
}
```

And on ACTIVITY B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(//Set your content view);

    final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  

    ArrayList<String> produtcs = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("products");


    final ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, produtcs);  


    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: OK THANKS but my question is how do I create ten other arraylist in the Activity B, one for each button clicked on the Activity A :) ?

Comment: you know how to fix this problem?